# is memcache used read quota of google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, blob

[image]

I used GWT 2.4 and GAE 1.7.4.In my datastore **i used blob for store image.**i alread put all data in **memcache** and after every refresh of my home page read **quota increase 1%**.

My Code is as below

```
 public List<CastDTO> getAll() {
    List<CastDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<CastDTO>();

    //Use Memcache more efficiently, Increase caching of frequently accessed shared data
    final MemcacheService syncCache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
    syncCache.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.INFO));
    List<Cast> cacheCastsList = (List<Cast>) syncCache.get(StaticData.CAST_LIST);

    if(cacheCastsList == null){
        cacheCastsList = castDAO.findAll();
        for (Cast cast : cacheCastsList) {
            dtoList.add(CastConverter.convert(cast));
            syncCache.put(cast.getCastName(), cast.getCastImage());
        }
        syncCache.put(StaticData.CAST_LIST, cacheCastsList);
    }else{
        for (Cast cast : cacheCastsList) {
            dtoList.add(CastConverter.convert(cast));
        }
    }

    return dtoList;
}
```

Comment: (two years later :) First you store your castImages individually & then you store the whole list once again. In other words you are using twice as much space in Memcache. Are you aware of the fact? <joke>"Is that how you backup your data?"</joke>

Answer (score 0):

No the memcache not use a read cota by default. 
But if you use datas from the memcache to identify other datas in the datastore you use the cota.

Can you see in the memcache viewer if after perform a "Flush Cache" and reload your home page for the second time the miss count increase ?

If your Miss count increase after the seconde home page load you have probably a wrong implementation in your code.